# How in C# to cast using a variable representing a type for the result of reflection .Invoke()

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have a method that returns *byte[]* but for now would like to avoid using generics on the method to supply the return type. I currently pass a parameter into this method that has the details of the *type* of the data that will be serialized to the *byte[]* return result.

**Question:**

> How do I perform a dynamic cast of the result of *.Invoke()*?

I'm using reflection to call a method on a class the output of this is object and this result needs to be cast.

**The Code:**

```
public byte[] SomeMethod(/* some params */)
{
    MethodInfo info = /* ... */ .GetMethod(methodToCall);

    //Here I want to perform a dynamic cast:
    return (info.Invoke(classToCall, methodParams)).Serialize();

    //if I was to just have the method fixed to a type it would look like:
    return (info.Invoke(classToCall, methodParams) as SomeType).Serialize();

    //NOTE: .Serialize() is just my own extension method
}
```

What I have tried **without success:**

```
//with returnType as a string
var dynamicType = Type.GetType(returnType);

(info.Invoke(classToCall, methodParams) as dynamicType).Serialize();
```

Also some other variations with *typeof()*, *GetTypeHandle*, *.ReflectedType*

---

Am I missing something simple and/or obvious, or am I just trying to do something strange/silly?

**Additional note:** the *SomeMethod* is an override of a method of a class hence not wanting to have the method support a generic type.

Comment: I tried to cram as many key words into the question title, it may not read as well as it should...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common misunderstanding that the cast operator really does anything in this situation.  You either want to **convert** from the type that `Invoke` returned to another type, or it already is the type you want it to be even though `Invoke` is declared to return `object`.

Since I don't think you want to convert anything, you have to first recognize that the return value of calling `Invoke` like this:

```
var result = info.Invoke(classToCall, methodParams);
```

the `result` will be a variable of type `object` but the value in that variable **will already be the type you want to cast it to**.  You just don't know exactly what it is.  And you need to know what it is to call `Serialize`.

Now, you have this extension method, or set of overloaded extension methods that operate on a compile time specified initial `this` parameter.  One of them matches the type of the return **value** of the `Invoke` call.

In order to choose which of these methods to call, you need to use reflection **again** to get a `MethodInfo` matching the right type and just call your `Serialize` method.  It might help if it weren't an extension method because now you have no easy way to look up the extension method the same way the compiler does at compile time only.  Extension method matching is extremely laborious and not suited to dynamic invocation.

Instead, if you want to use reflection a second time to call `Serialize`, without having a giant switch statement, then you need to have a utility class with all the `Serialize` methods as public overloads within that class.  At least that is one way to approach the problem.

Comment: Great work Rick, thanks for this direction idea, looks to be working well and I agree that trying to achieve this with extension methods would be more more difficult/not-possible.

Answer (score 0):

2 methods come to mind if you don't want to use generics.

First method would be to cast based on methodToCall. Not too elegant.

```
if (methodToCall == "method1")
  return ((obj1)info.Invoke(classToCall, methodParams)).Serialize();
else if (methodToCall == "method2")
 return ((obj2)info.Invoke(classToCall, methodParams)).Serialize();
```

Second method would be to create a super class that is inherited by all possible return types of your methodToCall. The super class would have .Serialize() declared and inherited by the sub classes.

```
interface mySuperClass
{
  byte[] Serialize();
}
```

Cast as mySuperClass

```
return (info.Invoke(classToCall, methodParams) as mySuperclass).Serialize();
```

This may not work too well if you have a very large number of possible return types. Happy coding.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but not the direction I need, this might help someone else so good to have it attached to this question :)